# How can i avoid calling api inside setInterval multiple times in socket on new connection?

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I am trying to implement socket where user request to a function with id and after having an id i am hitting an api every second and emitting the response to the user

Problem: Whenever new user request to the same id its again calling the same api with same id

Objective: I am trying to achieve if setInterval is already running with the same id then it should not call again rather it just start emitting the response.

My code:

```
socket.on('fancy' , async (data) => {
    checkInterval = setInterval(async _ => {
      callapi(data.match_id).then( fancy => {
        socket.emit(`fancy_${data.match_id}`, fancy)
      })
    }, 1000)
  })

callapi = (id) => {
  var options = {
    'method': 'POST',
    'url': 'url',
    formData: {
      'id': id
    }
  };
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request(options, function (error, response) {
      let resp = {}
      if (error) reject(error)
      resolve({status: 'success', data: JSON.parse(response.body).data})
    });
  })
}
```

Any suggestion is of great help!

Comment: so, something like [this](https://pastebin.com/c6Kz7vaT) ? - I got rid of `async` in that code, since you never use `await` - but you can put it back in if you really need to

Comment: @JaromandaX Still the api is calling  for all the client connected.

Comment: Oh, so you want only one interval running ...

Comment: Yes if request if of same id

Comment: huh? same as what?

Comment: If  multiple user is requesting data for same id. I dont want to call api multiple times for all users. rather i want to give response directly because for that id already one setInterval is running

Comment: so you're almost trying to create a pub/sub type pattern - that's going to be a little more complex

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257164/discussion-between-piyush-and-jaromanda-x).

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://pastebin.com/sQUYwdrT) is a good starting point?

Comment: @JaromandaX Thanks for the wonderful solution. It works like a charm. Just one more thing how can i clear setInterval if all connected user disconnected who was listening to that id

Comment: ahh, so you want a way to "unsubscribe" as well

Comment: OK, I added an answer with the original code, and two alternatives to "unsubscribing"

Answer (score 1):

The way I would appropach this is to create a `Class` to handle the multiple fancys -

For completeness, this is what I sent in the comments yesterday - it addresses the requirements in the question.

```
class Fancy {
    static fancies = {};
    static add(match_id, socket) {
        if (!Fancy.fancies[match_id]) {
            Fancy.fancies[match_id] = new Fancy(match_id);
        }
        Fancy.fancies[match_id].subscribe(socket);
    }
 
    subscribers = [];
 
    constructor(match_id) {
        this.match_id = match_id;
        this.checkInterval = setInterval(async () => {
            const fancy = await callapi(this.match_id);
            this.subscribers.forEach((socket) =>
                socket.emit(`fancy_${this.match_id}`, fancy)
            );
        });
    }
    subscribe(socket) {
        if (!this.subscribers.find((sock) => sock === socket)) {
            this.subscribers.push(socket);
        }
    }
}
 
socket.on('fancy' , ({match_id}) => Fancy.add(match_id, socket));
```

Note: While this is a `class` - only the static `add` method needs to be used.

Of course, this does not handle disconnections, or the ability for a user to "unsubscribe" from a "fancy" - as per comment

So, to expand on that code, it's not too different - just add a couple of static methods, and a few instance methods

`remove` static method - the inverse of the existing `add`, and a `disconnect` static method that removes the socket from all instances.

For instance methods, adding an `unsubscribe`, `start` and `stop` method

```
class Fancy {
    static fancies = {};
    static add(match_id, socket) {
        if (!Fancy.fancies[match_id]) {
            Fancy.fancies[match_id] = new Fancy(match_id);
        }
        Fancy.fancies[match_id].subscribe(socket);
    }
    
    static remove(match_id, socket) {
        Fancy.fancies[match_id]?.unsubscribe(socket);
    }
    
    static disconnect(socket) {
        Fancy.fancies.forEach(fancy => fancy.unsubscribe(socket));
    }
    
    // instance properties/methods
    
    subscribers = [];

    constructor(match_id) {
        this.match_id = match_id;
    }
    
    start() {
        if (!this.checkInterval) {
            this.checkInterval = setInterval(async () => {
                const fancy = await callapi(this.match_id);
                this.subscribers.forEach((socket) =>
                    socket.emit(`fancy_${this.match_id}`, fancy)
                );
            });
        }
    }
    
    stop() {
        clearInterval(this.setInterval);
        this.checkInterval = null;
    }
    
    unsubscribe(socket) {
        this.subscribers = this.subscribers.filter(sock => sock !== socket);
        if (this.subscribers.length === 0) {
            this.stop();
        }
    }
    
    subscribe(socket) {
        if (!this.subscribers.find((sock) => sock === socket)) {
            this.subscribers.push(socket);
            if (this.subscribers.length === 1) {
                this.start();
            }
        }
    }
}

socket.on('fancy' , ({match_id}) => Fancy.add(match_id, socket));
socket.on('unfancy' , ({match_id}) => Fancy.remove(match_id, socket));
socket.on('close', () => Fancy.disconnect(socket));
```

An alternative to the `stop`/`start` methods would be to keep the interval running, however only making the API request if there are any "subscribers"

This simplifies the code somewhat, just adding one instance method (unsubscribe)

Something like this:

```
class Fancy {
    static fancies = {};
    static add(match_id, socket) {
        if (!Fancy.fancies[match_id]) {
            Fancy.fancies[match_id] = new Fancy(match_id);
        }
        Fancy.fancies[match_id].subscribe(socket);
    }
    
    static remove(match_id, socket) {
        Fancy.fancies[match_id]?.unsubscribe(socket);
    }
    
    static disconnect(socket) {
        Fancy.fancies.forEach(fancy => fancy.unsubscribe(socket));
    }
    
    // instance properties/methods
    
    subscribers = [];

    constructor(match_id) {
        this.match_id = match_id;
        this.checkInterval = setInterval(async () => {
            if (this.subscribers.length) {
                const fancy = await callapi(this.match_id);
                this.subscribers.forEach((socket) =>
                    socket.emit(`fancy_${this.match_id}`, fancy)
                );
            }
        });
    }
    
    unsubscribe(socket) {
        this.subscribers = this.subscribers.filter(sock => sock !== socket);
    }
    
    subscribe(socket) {
        if (!this.subscribers.find((sock) => sock === socket)) {
            this.subscribers.push(socket);
        }
    }
}
```

Personally, I would use the last solution, there's no performance hit in having an interval that effectively does nothing when there are no subscribers